# Llamar a una función dentro de una promesa

Tags: nodejs, promesas

Dentro de una promesa quiero invocar a una función.

Me sale el siguiente error:

> (node:7828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property `verificarAcceso` of `undefined`

Creo que es problema de alcance.

Código:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class Evaluacion {
    let promise =new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject){
            this.verificarAcceso(nombreEvaluacion,function (err,res) {
                console.log('consultiti', res);
                resolve(res);
            })
        }
    );
    verificarAcceso(nombre,done){
        let acceso=false;
        bdEvaluacion.accesoEvauacion('SI', function (err,result) {
            result.forEach(function (current) {

            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: No puedo probar tu código, pero sí que parece un problema con el alcance de la variable que intentas usar. Prueba a poner `let $this = this;` justo antes del `let promise...` y cambia `this.verificarAcceso` por `$this.verificarAcceso`. ¿Te funciona entonces o te sigue dando error?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si funciona, deja tu respuesta porfavor

Comment: Genial :) Ahora lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como indicas en la pregunta, es un problema con el alcance de la variable y el valor de `this`, que dentro de la promesa no es lo que esperas. Para solucionarlo puedes crear una variable que contenga `this` y que podrás usar dentro de la promesa. Algo así:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class Evaluacion {

    let $this = this;

    let promise =new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject){
            $this.verificarAcceso(nombreEvaluacion,function (err,res) {
                console.log('consultiti', res);
                resolve(res);
            })
        }
    );
    verificarAcceso(nombre,done){
        let acceso=false;
        bdEvaluacion.accesoEvauacion('SI', function (err,result) {
            result.forEach(function (current) {

            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: solucionaste mi problema!!!